# Gradle- Test library project. Manifest merge

Tags: android, testing, gradle, android-studio, android-library

I am trying to test Android library project. The test fails because different name in the androidManifest application name.
In my main Manifest the application name is:  android:name=".MyApplication".
It seems like the test manifest that generate automatically has an empty name.
This is the comment I get during the test:
    **:A360AndroidSDK:processTestTestManifest
[manifestMerge2804395194685277367.xml:5, manifestMerge5685073004339393716.xml:11] Main manifest has  but library uses name='.MyApplication'.**

In the log cat I get the error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.test.MyApplication.
```

Can I fix this merge or write the right value for the application name in the generate Manifest?

I run the test on the library with Gradle connectedCheck.